# What is the wrong with this verilog code?

Tags: verilog

Can anybody help me? I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
module add( a ,b , sum,overFlow);
  input [31:0] a;
  input  [31:0] b;
output overFlow;

  output [31:0]sum;
  reg sum;

  always @(a or b)
  begin
    sum=a+b;


  end
  initial
  begin
    if( a[30]==0 &&  b[30]==0 &&  sum[30]==1) overFlow = 1b’1;
   else if( a[30] == 1 &&  b[30] == 1 &&  sum[30] == 0) overFlow = 1b’1;

end

endmodule
```

the error is :

> "** Error: C:/altera/13.1/add.v(13): near "b": syntax error,
>   unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ';'
>   ** Error: C:/altera/13.1/add.v(14): near "b": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ';'
>   ** Error: C:/altera/13.1/add.v(22): near "endmodule": syntax error, unexpected endmodule "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `1b’1` to `1'b1`.  Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section "5.7 Numbers".

Once you fix that, you'll probably have other compile errors.

Change:

```
output overFlow;

  output [31:0]sum;
  reg sum;
```

to:

```
  output reg overFlow;
  output reg [31:0] sum;
```

`overFlow` must be a `reg` because you are making a procedural assignment to it (in an `initial` block).